# What is an rId in R?

Tags: r

I'm making a power point, but I can't seem to understand what an rId is or how it relates to src. I know src relates to source, but I'm not sure what Id is referring to. Is an Id just another way to call another function?

Error:

```
Error in external_img(material_shapes[stat_headers$directions$avg_lease_rate]) : 
src must be a string starting with 'rId' or an existing image filename
```

Edit:
Line emitting error

```
ph_with(value = external_img(material_shapes[stat_headers$directions$avg_lease_rate]), location = ph_location_label(ph_label = "Arrow Placeholder 4", newlabel = "Arrow 4"))
```

Comment: It would help to include the code that generated the error. I assume you are using `officer` ? The error indicates that an image file cannot be found. Perhaps the path to the image in your code is incorrect.

Comment: @neilfws yes I am using officer. I included an edit with the line I know the error is coming from. The code itself is over 1k lines

Comment: So the value of `material_shapes[stat_headers$directions$avg_lease_rate]` should be either a string starting with 'rId' or an existing image filename. If it isn't one of those things, you'll get the error.